Generic Parameter For function not accepting child objects
I have following type:
type VerifyResultFunction = <T extends ResultBase>(result: T) => boolean;

Now I have class with extends ResultBase
class XResult extends ResultBase {
  test!: string[];
}

Finally I try to define my own VerifyResultFunction, which would check XResult Objects:
let verifyX: verifyResultFunction = (result: XResult) => {
  result.test.length == 33 && result.id == 12;
}

This code runs fine, but I see following warning in VS Code:

Type '(result: XResult) => void' is not assignable to type 'verifyResultFunction'.
Types of parameters 'result' and 'result' are incompatible.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'XResult'.
Property 'test' is missing in type 'ResultBase' but required in type 'XResult'.ts(2322)

What am I missing?

Please [edit] to make this code a [mre]. What's ResultBase? Is the type verifyResultFunction or VerifyResultFunction? Why doesn't your function return anything if it's supposed to return boolean? I'm sure the issue here is that your type parameter is incorrectly scoped (generic functions have their type argument chosen by callers, not implementers. If you want the implementer to choose, you need to make it a generic type, not a generic function, but without a [mre] it's hard to demonstrate properly.

Here, this playground link shows the problem and its fix. Please [edit] your code to use my Bad code as your [mre] (minus the demonstration as for why your code is bad)... or I'll do it if you want. Then I can write up the answer, if you agree that the Good code fully addresses the question. Let me know how to proceed.
